# User & Role Claim to manage Enterprise scale Permissions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have Business.API and i want to apply user permissions to each methods. i'm working with :

```
OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
AuthorizeAttribute
```

there are a huge number of permissions on each controller and a user may have a float number of Roles by admin's prefers.

first problem is about limiting access to each content. for example i have a limitation on NEWS; a user only able to see about 5 category of NEWS and he is restricted to access to "Not Secret" NEWS. and a worst case will be rage limitation (e.g forbidding a user to access to some NEWS in a time span or on specific NEWS)

in above Permission set, i need to have so many flexibility for each kind of my contents.

is it possible with a simple AuthorizeAttribute ?

if i was able to handle this one, it may better to use a custom collection of permission, i could add so many roles and restriction on each Token and at each request it was about checking relevant permissions.
i need to something like it (i think).

Comment: I don't know if you have ever heard of ASP.NET Identity Management system.

Comment: If you haven't here you can start : https://www.asp.net/identity

Comment: Thanks. i wasn't familiar with this technology. i will read.

Comment: You're welcome. it is Role and Claim based and almost so flexible with any idea you got on your mind (algorithm based)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, you have to do a couple of things.

1. Asp.net Claims - Your solution lies in the `ClaimsPrincipal`, just forget about the Roles because, in more broader perspective, the WCF declining started as it cannot handle the claims.

   [Claim Principle Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsprincipal(v=vs.110).aspx%20'ClaimsPrincipal%20Library')
2. You have to issue the claims from your server and need to inject the claims in the OWIN pipeline at the time of the request.

**Note:** **You can issue claims Utilizing ClaimsPrincipal Class**

3. The Third step is to handle the claims inside the web api. For that, I can suggest you the simple library implemented by `leastprivilages` i.e. **ResourceAuthorization**.

   [Resource Authorization](https://github.com/IdentityModel/Thinktecture.IdentityModel/blob/master/source/Owin.ResourceAuthorization/AppBuilderExtensions.cs)
4. In this way, you can authorize the resources like **Secret News**, **News** etc. at each resource level.
5. If you don't want to do so, then you have to implement the **CustomAuthorization** which is inherited from **AuthorizeAttribute**.
6. From my experience, I will suggest you distribute your authorization in two steps i.e. at controller level check for the authorizing cookie and then at the resource i.e. api method level check for the resource access.